# Explain Keyword-Only Arguments (VarArgs) in Python

Tags: python, variadic-functions

Please see the code below:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: total.py

def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, vegetables=50, fruits=100))
```

Can someone please explain how is *numbers and **keywords picking up the arguments?
A simple explaination is very much appreciayed
Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls confused you?  Can you be more specific about which paragraph was not complete enough?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your code `numbers` is assigned the (1,2,3) tuple. `keywords` is assigned a dictionary, containing `vegetables` and `fruits`.

One star (`*`) defines positional arguments. This means that you can receive any number of arguments. You can treat the passed arguments as a tuple.

Two stars (`**`) define keywords arguments.

The reference material is available [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls).

#### Examples

Python 2.x (before keyword-only arguments)

```
def foo(x, y, foo=None, *args): print [x, y, foo, args]

foo(1, 2, 3, 4)            --> [1, 2, 3, (4, )]  # foo == 4
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, foo=True)  --> TypeError
```

Python 3.x (with keyword-only arguments)

```
def foo(x, y, *args, foo=None): print([x, y, foo, args])

foo(1, 2, 3, 4)           --> [1, 2, None, (3, 4)]  # foo is None
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, foo=True) --> [1, 2, True, (3, 4)]

def combo(x=None, *args, y=None): ...  # 2.x and 3.x styles in one function
```

Although a seasoned programmer understands what happened in 2.x, it's counter-intuitive (a positional argument gets bound to `foo=` regardless of keyword arguments as long as there are enough positional arguments)

Python 3.x introduces more intuitive keyword-only arguments with [PEP-3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) (keyword arguments after varargs can only be bound by name)

Comment: Thanks - more on this - so does that mean first argument is always a list/tuple and the second as dictionary?

Comment: Hi S.Lott - i read kgiannakakis explaination and then read http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments - it cleared my doubt - Thanks for checking

Comment: @kgiannakakis: the foo after running your Python 2.x example ought to be `3`, oughtn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's breakdown the function first.

This total function takes three parameters.

1. initial=5 =>this is a keyword argument.
2. *numbers  =>this is a also known as *args. You can pass any number of arguments as you want.
3. **keywords =>this is a keyword argument like a dictionary, each key that is associated with a given value.

==========================================

count = initial

*we know that initial is a keyword argument that contains a value of 5.
 So the value of 5 is now assigned to a variable called count.

for number in numbers:

*the number is a placeholder variable for numbers.

*we know that numbers is an arbitrary parameter so it can take any number of arguments or values.

*so now the number is going to contain the arguments which is passed in the numbers parameter while executing the function.

count += number

*each time it loops through the numbers arguments and adds the count to the number and returns a count

*when count is 5, it loops through the argument and adds the first instance of the argument. This will be repeated until the loop gets exhausted.

for key in keywords:

*this is tricky because this time the parameter is dictionary type which contains keys and corresponding values to that keys.

count += keywords[key]

return count

100 + 50 + (10, 1, 2, 3) => 166.

I know this answer is too big but understanding the underlying concept of each function is a core strength of a well rounded programmer.