# owlready installed, but error in importing

Tags: python, python-2.7, owlready

I have already installed owlready, I am working with python 2.7, owlready version installed is Owlready 0.3. When I try to import owlready into a script, I get following error:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Keyword-Only Arguments (VarArgs) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255091/explain-keyword-only-arguments-varargs-in-python)

Comment: This syntax is only supported in Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: how to use owlready in python2

Comment: Apparently you can't. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Owlready says: *"Owlready (previously named Ontopy) is a module for ontology-oriented programming in Python 3."*

Comment: I am getting the same error in Python 3