# Default values for positional function arguments in Python?

Tags: python

I was going trough some code, and I came across the following function:

```py
def foo(self, arg1=1, *, arg2=2):
    pass
```

I was surprised to see keyword arguments on the left side of the `*`, the positional arguments. I notice then that I can call `foo` in both of the following ways:

```py
>>> foo(1)
>>> foo(arg1=1)
```

I think I would be expecting the second call to fail as I am calling `foo` using a named argument by providing the keyword `arg1`.

With that said, am I using positional arguments in both scenarios, or is the second call to `foo` a named argument?

Comment: the second call is a named argument.

Comment: Relevant info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302007/3589609

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting I saw that topic but it does not answer the question

Comment: @RenatoDamas I agree, that's why it's just here in the comments. Thought it might be useful, as it helped me get a better understanding. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting then I give you a thumbs up ! ;)

Answer (score 11):

The best sentence that I found that best describes this is:

"*The trick here is to realize that a “keyword argument” is a concept of the call site, not the declaration. But a “keyword only argument” is a concept of the declaration, not the call site.*"

Below is a concise explanation copied from [here](https://medium.com/@boxed/keyword-argument-confusion-in-python-59105c5a1159) in case the link dies at some point.

```
def bar(a,    # <- this parameter is a normal python parameter
        b=1,  # <- this is a parameter with a default value
        *,    # <- all parameters after this are keyword only
        c=2,  # <- keyword only argument with default value
        d):   # <- keyword only argument without default value
    pass
```

Answer (score 8):

The `arg1` argument is allowed to be called as either a positional argument, or a keyword argument.

As of Python 3.8, it is possible to specify some arguments as positional only. See [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/). Prior to 3.8, this isn't possible unless you write a python C extension.

The 3.8 syntax looks like this (directly from the PEP):

```
def name(positional_only_parameters, /, positional_or_keyword_parameters,
         *, keyword_only_parameters): ...
```

...prior to 3.8, the only legal syntax is this:

```
def name(positional_or_keyword_parameters, *, keyword_only_parameters): ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the similarity in syntax, there is no relationship between keyword arguments and parameters with default values.

`key=value` is used both to assign a default value to a *parameter* when the function is *defined*, and to pass an argument for a parameter when the function is *called*.

A parameter without a default value can be assigned using a keyword argument:

```
def foo(a):
    return a + 3

assert foo(a=5) == 8
```

A parameter with a default value can be assigned without a keyword argument:

```
def foo(a=5):
    return a + 3

assert foo() == 8
assert foo(1) == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a complex answer by using the * like the argument ( the Python version, define and use it ).

In your case:

```
>>> foo(1,2,)
>>> foo(1,2)
```

Note that:
Try to use this and see the difference ( without self ):

```
>>> def foo( arg1=1, *, arg2=2):
...     pass
...
>>> foo(arg1=1,arg2=2)
>>> def foo( arg1=1, *, arg2=2):
...     pass
...
>>> foo(arg1=1,arg2=2)
>>> foo(arg1=1)
>>> foo(arg1=1,)
>>> foo(arg2=2)
>>> foo(arg2=2,1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
>>> foo(2,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
>>> foo(arg1=1,2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

- One star * defines positional arguments (you can receive any number of arguments and treat the passed arguments as a tuple);
- Two stars ** define keywords arguments.

A good example comes from [this tutorial](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) (the keyword-only arguments without positional arguments part):

```
def with_previous(iterable, *, fillvalue=None):
    """Yield each iterable item along with the item before it."""
    previous = fillvalue
    for item in iterable:
        yield previous, item
        previous = item

>>> list(with_previous([2, 1, 3], fillvalue=0))
[(0, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3)]
```

That its value could be sent as positional arguments.

See [this tutorial](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/understanding-args-and-kwargs/) for more info about arguments.

Python 3.x introduces more intuitive keyword-only arguments with PEP-3102 (you can specify * in the argument list).

One good alternative answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255091/explain-keyword-only-arguments-varargs-in-python):